# Append new data into the google sheet using python script and cron job

Tags: python, google-sheets, cron

I have a scheduler data in google sheets where people put in the event details and mark them as scheduled. I only want to get those rows where the data is marked as completed (using column 'Status') print the rows into a new google sheet.

All good till now and I have created a script that pulls all the data and then filter the completed status only.

I want to run this script daily and for that I am using a cron job, that reruns the script.

Now the issue is I don't want to replace or publish the entire scheduler data again daily as it there's already other info in the google sheets that I do not want to override, what I want is that daily when the script runs, append only those rows who's status has changed from 'Scheduled' to 'Completed'. Are there any good solutions to achieve that? or should I create two more separate sheets to compare previous data from current data and get the new rows?

Please note, It could happen that an event was marked scheduled for 31-03-2023 and got marked completed today 1-05-2023.

These are some of the columns

```
Event_Date  Start Time (24hr)   Status  Event   Client
```

Comment: In your situation, how about the following flow? 1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet. 2. Create the updated value. 3. Update the Spreadsheet using the updated value. Unfortunately, I cannot know your script and your Spreadsheet. So, I couldn't propose a clear sample script. So, I proposed the flow for achieving your goal. I apologize for this. By the way, I cannot understand `Please note, It could happen that an event was marked scheduled for 31-03-2023 and got marked completed today 1-05-2023.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?